# Left shift is giving wrong results

Tags: vb.net, bit-shift

Here is my code:

```
dim message as byte() = {5,4,3,2,1}
dim result = 244
dim result2 = 244
result = result + CUInt(CUInt(message(4) << 8))
result2 = result2 + CUInt(CUInt(1 << 8))  
console.WriteLine(result)
Console.WriteLine(result2)
```

and the result:

```
 245  
 500
```

I don't understand why even though `message(4)` is equal to `1` why I don't get the expect results.
`result2` gives the expected result but I want to be able to read the value directly from the array.

Answer (score 0):

well it was a coding error

the proper code is
    result = result + CUInt(CUInt(message(4)) << 8)
i can see now that i need to get the CUint of message(4) prior to left shift